# Finding if an array is in a 2D array

Tags: javascript

I want to know whether if an array is inside of a 2D array.

This is what I tried:

```
var x=[1,2];
var y=[[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3]];

y.includes(x); //should return true
```

Comment: Even  though the 2 arrays look the same...they are not the same array reference. `[1,2] !== [1,2]` so you can't directly compare them as objects

Comment: if you wanted to use a library, underscoreJs has `_.findIndex(y, x)` which would return the position inside `y` http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex, or you could make it a truth test with `_.findIndex(y,x) >== 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with chained array methods!

```
var ar = [
    [1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3]
];

hasDuplicates(ar, [1,"1"]); //false
hasDuplicates(ar, [1,1]); //true

//Use some to determine at least 1 inner array matches
function hasDuplicates(array, valueToCheck) {
    return array.some(function(a, i) {
        //Check each inner arrays index, and verify that it equals on the same index of the array we want to check
        return a.every(function(ax, ix) {
            return valueToCheck[ix] === ax; //triple equals for equality!
        })
    });
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a3rq70hL/1/

Comment: Nice usage of some and every, haven't seen those two in quite a while :)

Answer (score 4):

you can create a hash:

```js
var ar = [
    [1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3]
];

var hash = {};
for(var i = 0 ; i < ar.length; i += 1) {
    hash[ar[i]] = i;
}

var val = [1,2];

if(hash.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
    document.write(hash[val]);
}
```

Comment: Won't differentiate between `["1", "2"]` and `[1,2]` - not sure if that matters for this case. +1 either way.

Comment: Yea if we assume all values in the inner arrays will be integers and not strings then this is great solution!